# React Vite app constantly refreshing (+ docker & traefik)

Tags: reactjs, docker, websocket, vite

The app is dockerized and I am using traefik.
It constantly reloads (every 3 seconds).

In the console I can see that the error is "Websocket connection to wss://mywebsite.com:3000/ failed".

If it helps, my vite.config.js is simply:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding in  vite.config.js the following:

```
server: {
    hmr: { clientPort: 443 },
  },
```

Hopefully it can help the next one with this issue!